# Flushing a Hashmap of custom Objects in JSON Format

Tags: java, android, json, jackson

I have a this map:

```
HashMap<LatLng,ArrayList<String>> dictionary = new  HashMap<LatLng,ArrayList<String>>() ;
```

and I'm trying to flush it to disk in JSON format using jackson like this:

```
ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
mapper.writeValue(new File(MyApplication.getOfflineData()+"/Dictionary.json"), dictionary);
```

this is how is written the json file:

```
"lat/lng: (39.151783,20.97455)": [
"/mnt/sdcard/Android/data/example.perifereia_hpeirou/files/lala/photos/pic1.nomedia",
"/mnt/sdcard/Android/data/example.perifereia_hpeirou/files/lala/photos/pic2.nomedia",
"/mnt/sdcard/Android/data/example.perifereia_hpeirou/files/lala/photos/pic3.nomedia",
"/mnt/sdcard/Android/data/example.perifereia_hpeirou/files/lala/photos/pic4.nomedia"
]
```

I think this is not correct. I think the "lat/lng": shouldn't exist, how can I correct this?
Thank you for your time.

Comment: Could you show your LatLng class?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you are using complex POJO class as a key in a `Map`, `Jackson` have to generate property name using this class. Simplest implementation is using `toString` method. In `JSON` we are not able to create complex property name. Object can not be a property. To solve your problem I propose to create new POJO class which contains `LatLng` and `List<String>` properties. See example:

```
class Root {

    private LatLng latLng;
    private List<String> values;

    //getters,setters
}
```

Now, your `JSON` will be looking like this:

```
{
  "latLng" : {
    "lat" : "39.151783",
    "lng" : "20.97455"
  },
  "values" : [ "/mnt/sdcard/Android/data/example.perifereia_hpeirou/files/lala/photos/pic1.nomedia", "/mnt/sdcard/Android/data/example.perifereia_hpeirou/files/lala/photos/pic2.nomedia" ]
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Just flush out the values of the HashMap.

```
mapper.writeValue(new File(MyApplication.getOfflineData()+"/Dictionary.json"), dictionary.values())
```

Or override the toString() of LatLng if you want to customise representation of LatLng.

Comment: can't override it LatLng isn't my class I'll try the former and get back to u

Comment: Possibly wrap LatLong in a custom class and then override toString()